# How can I instantiate the `execution` object in a Camunda JavaScript service task?

Tags: javascript, bpmn, camunda

I see lots of JavaScript references and code snippets on the forum/documentation ([like this one](https://forum.camunda.org/t/create-and-resolve-incidents-through-scripts-javascript-examples-internal-api/3728)) where the `execution` object is used for a range of useful things, such as:

```
execution.createIncident(String incidentType, String configuration);
execution.resolveIncident(String incidentId);
execution.setVariable("name", value);
```

However, nowhere have I seen an example of how to instantiate the `execution` object, and when I try to use it I get an error like this:

```
The process could not be started. :
Cannot instantiate process definition Finswitch_Tx:14:42ef803b-67df-11e8-a127-0242ac11001b: Unable to 
evaluate script: ReferenceError: "execution" is not defined in <eval> at line number 7
```

Please could you give me an example of how to instantiate access to that object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So a more comprehensive answer to this after some [help on the Camunda forum](https://forum.camunda.org/t/how-do-i-get-access-to-the-execution-object-in-javascript/7563/5).

According to [this documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/user-guide/process-engine/scripting/#variables-available-during-script-execution), *all process variables available in the current scope are available to the script by name, as well as some special variables: `execution`, `task` and `connector`*.

What's not clear in the documentation is that scripts in the **output variables of a connector** are running in a child (connector) scope, so while the `connector` object is available, the `execution` is not.  Some for the functionality on the execution instance can be accessed like this:

```
var execution = connector.getParentVariableScope();
var activityId = execution.getCurrentActivityId();
```

However, I see the object returned from  is actually an `AbstractVariableScope` so I'm not sure how far this can be used.

Similarly, inside the script of a **Task Listener**, the task instance is available, which corresponds to the DelegateTask interface.  Here the `execution` instance can be accessed as follows:

```
task.execution.getCurrentActivityId();
```

Within an **Execution Listener**, the `execution` instance is accessible directly.

```
execution.setVariable("testVar", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The delegateExecution/delegateTask objects you get from camunda are very complex context hooks that camunda creates based on the current execution state and hands it to the hooks (listener and delegate).
You cannot create that on your own.
If you need to access it, place your code in a Task/ExecutionListener or a delegate, than you have access to it automatically.

Comment: So are these objects only available in some of the places you can use JavaScript?  Perhaps they are not available for use in a Service Task output variable of type JavaScript?  `connector` is available, though, and it is mentioned as one of the 'special variables' along with execution [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/user-guide/process-engine/scripting/#variables-available-during-script-execution)